# Jquery, to set the display of an element width to block

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to code the jquery to set the display of an element width id "results" to block?

Not sure if it's right, sorry im new to programming, help will be appreciate, thank you.

```
$(document.ready(function(){
    $('results').width(display:none;);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not clear what you want here but  assuming you want to hide the results

```
$(document.ready(function(){

  $('#results').css({display:"none"}); //to hide
  $('#results').css({display:"block"}); //to show
})
```

or you can just use hide() and show()

```
 $('#results').hide();
 $('#results').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

if the element has an id tag with id as 'results' then

```
$('#results').css('display','block');
```

if the element has an classtag with class as 'results' then

```
$('.results').css('display','block');
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you want with this line  set the display of an element width id "results"  ... assuming it was a typo "set the display of an element with id "results" ".

```
 $('#results').css('display','block');
```